# How to get a response after using stream functionality?

Tags: node.js, minio

So, I'm getting an error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". I get that my code res.status(200).send(OK(fileObj, null, req)); is synchronous. I'm not sure how to get a response after all my streams are ready.

```
    try {

        const fileObj = [];

        const stream =  await minioClient.listObjects(bucket, '', true);


        await stream.on('data', async (obj, error) => { 

            await fileObj.push(obj);

            if (error) {

                console.log(error);

            }

            res.status(200).send(OK(fileObj, null, req));
        });

        stream.on('error', function (err) { 


            console.log(err);

        });  
    }

    catch (e) {

        console.log(e);

    }
```

Expected result: It shouldn't show me "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" response.

Comment: Use the `end` event which is only called when the stream is finished. `stream.on('end', () => res.send(OK(fileObj, null, req));)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you must send response on stream end event.

```
stream.once('end', _=> res.status(200).send('OK'));
```